# possible to use gulp-livereload to refresh the page on just a change, no save?

Tags: gulp, livereload, gulp-watch, gulp-livereload

Is it possible to use the node package [gulp-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload) to refresh the page on just a change, without pressing command+s to save the file you are editing?

Comment: With JavaScript plugins you can edit right in your browser and AngularJS does makes it particularly easy:
https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible (not only gulp-livereload, but all livereload plugins). From the [official site](http://livereload.com/):

> LiveReload monitors changes in the file system. As soon as you save a file, it is preprocessed as needed, and the browser is refreshed.

However, there is a plugin for Sublime Text and Chrome that offers CSS live editing, [Emmet Livestyle](http://livestyle.emmet.io/)